# Perl Imager::Screenshot not doing screenshot with default parameters

Tags: perl, screenshot

I have the following code:

```
use Imager::Screenshot 'screenshot';
my $img = screenshot(hwnd => 'active', 
    left => 450, 
    right => 200, 
    top => 50, 
    bottom => 50
);
$img->write(file => 'screenshot.png', type => 'png' ) || 
    print "Failed: ", $img->{ERRSTR} , "\n";
```

it prints:

> "Can't call method "write" on undefined value at line 3"

but when I do:

```
use Imager::Screenshot 'screenshot';
my $img = screenshot(hwnd => 'active', 
    left => 100, 
     right => 300, 
     top => 100, 
     bottom => 300
);

$img->write(file => 'screenshot.png', type => 'png' ) || 
     print "Failed: ", $img->{ERRSTR} , "\n";
```

It does take a screenshot. Why would the left, right, top and bottom values matter here?

EDIT:
After some research I found out that left param must be smaller than right param and top must be smaller than bottom.

Comment: Why `left` param value is higher than `right` param value in your first snippet? What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking the error? e.g.

`my $img = screenshot(...) or die Imager->errstr;`

edit: try this code:

```
use Imager::Screenshot 'screenshot';
my $img = screenshot(hwnd => 'active',
    left => 450, 
    right => 200, 
    top => 50, 
    bottom => 50
) or die Imager->errstr;
$img->write(file => 'screenshot.png', type => 'png' ) || 
    print "Failed: ", $img->errstr, "\n";
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. Sorry

Comment: Also, here's the source: https://github.com/tonycoz/imager-screenshot/blob/master/Screenshot.pm#L100 . You're getting an undefined because it's doing a `return;` (returning nothing)

Comment: @Grigor What is there not to understand? Since `screenshot` is failing, check for errors after the call to `screenshot`. Also, invoke the `errstr` method rather than accessing the internals of the object directly as njahnke shows.

Comment: he posted with 1 line, before editing it, thats why i didn't understand what he meant sinan unr.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that's the line that causes problems:

```
my $img = screenshot(
  hwnd => 'active', 
  left => 450, 
  right => 200, 
  top => 50, 
  bottom => 50
);
```

See, with `left` and `right` params set to positive values (i.e., > 0) we set starting and ending 'X-' coordinates. But that doesn't make sense for starting 'X' to be further from the leftmost edge of the window than ending 'X'. The same story goes with `top` and `bottom` values equality.

If what you want is 'get me something of that window that's 450 pixels from the left, and 200 pixels from the right side, and 50 pixels from both top and bottom edges', use this:

```
my $img = screenshot(
  hwnd => 'active', 
  left => -200, 
  right => -450, 
  top => -50, 
  bottom => -50
);
```